# load xml file in php - missing access rights?

Tags: php, xml, access-rights

I want to read a XML file from a certain link with the following code

```
$filename = 'http://XXXXX/rss.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

When I try, I get the following error messages:

```
 wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 

failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in 

I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

Whats the problem? Can it be that the server doesn´t support simplexml_load_file?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen=0` is the problem. Set it to true/1 to allow this action, or try do download the file first.

Comment: Ok, I just saw that I can´t set it to true with my provider. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `allow_url_fopen` is set to `0`, you have no permissions to acces URL objects like files. Read [official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) for more information.

You can not change this value via .htaccess, so you have to set `allow_url_fopen=1` in your `php.ini` file. If you're using a shared hosting or some kind of it, you should contact hosting technical support and describe them your problem.